# clear validation summary mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using mvc 3 unobtrusive concept for validation . It is working fine at client/server side.The problem is that it wont clear until I hit the server again.

Is there any extra code i have to write to clear validation summary ?

Comment: Yeah you need to add the code that is working fine on my laptop. Can you see it?

Answer (score 9):

code to clear the validation summary:

```
function clearValidationSummary() {
    var container = $('form').find('[data-valmsg-summary="true"]');
    var list = container.find('ul');

    if (list && list.length) {
        list.empty();
        container.addClass('validation-summary-valid').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); // IMPORTANT: this line MUST be *before* Html.BeginForm()

Have a look at this link:
http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx

Regards
Navish

http://findnavish.livejournal.com

Comment: hi Navish,

thanx for your reply.

But this link provides solution for mvc2 . As i am working on mvc3.
Validation part in both are totally different as mvc3 has introduce unobtrusive javascript concept.